# High Voltage Supply with LT1308A

Tags: integrated-circuit, circuit-design

I am trying to build a circuit that outputs ~180V for a nixie watch using the LT1308A. I'm modifying the following circuit found in the [datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1308abfb.pdf) on page 17:

[image: LT1308A High Voltage]

Now my circuit is essentially the same, only removing the voltage doubler, changing the transformer from a 1:12 to a 1:10, and changing the feedback resistors to output 180V.

[image: Modified Circuit]

Though the output ranges between -50V and 243V, not the 180V I am expecting.

[image: Wall of Green]

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You have neither cap nor rectifier on the output.  You need both, and they need to be in an arrangement that insures zero (or at least controlled) DC current through the transformer secondary.  If all else fails, put the doubler back in!

Comment: I remember when all diode Ref Des.'s had to be called CR instead of D to remind us they are current rectifiers.